How to break symmetry of a polynomial ideal to simplify Groebner basis?
I have an ideal $I$ generated by a set of polynomials $\{ p_i \}$. There are some variable permutations to which the ideal is symmetric. By this I mean (apologies if there is a standard term for this) the polynomials themselves are not necessarily symmetric to these permutations, but the ideal itself is symmetric to these permutations: if a polynomial $f \in I$ then permuted($f$) $\in I$.
Unfortunately, this means that if a prime decomposition of $I$ has prime ideals that break the symmetry, then there needs to be all the permuted copies of that prime ideal in the decomposition as well.
This is making the Groebner basis much too large to calculate, when it may be much more manageable if I could somehow "break" the symmetry, and calculate the Groebner basis (and find the prime decomposition) without all the "duplicate" permuted primes.
Are there known tricks of adjusting either the ring or the generator set, to allow breaking the symmetry to simplify such calculations?
To give an example of what I mean by a computational "trick", here is one that was taught to me when I was first learning about computer algebra systems and Groebner bases. It is often advantageous to 'encode' any external knowledge one may know about about the solution space of an ideal, into the Groebner basis calculation. For example, if I know some prime component(s) require a particular variable $x$ to be non-zero, I can encode this by adding another variable $s$, and including the polynomial $xs - 1$ in the generators. This will 'remove' the components for which $x$ must be zero.
I'm hoping there are known tips and tricks for simplifying calculations with symmetric ideals.

For concreteness could you please add the example where the Groebner basis is much too large to calculate?

@RicardoBuring Here's a smaller example to play with that is calculable with S_4 x S_2 symmetry, https://gist.github.com/bafflingbits/33b783e82434e57b087ea0174e79c737 . And here's an example where I cannot calculate the Groebner basis with S_6 x S_2 symmetry. https://gist.github.com/bafflingbits/9a4622078a080049e8bb776433922a38

Can you also concretely indicate (permutation groups) what symmetries exist in the examples?  This is a bit hard to see from the generators. Thx.

@ahulpke To be more explicit, in those examples we have variables "indexed" by two tuples of integers (n1,c1) and (n2,c2), with n1 ≠ n2. The order of "indexing" by the two tuples does not matter: variable[(n1,c1), (n2,c2)] = variable[(n2,c2), (n1,c1)]. Furthermore, in both examples the number of choices for n or c are less than 10, so we can reduce the number of variables by the naming convention "w{n1}{n2}{c1}{c2}" where n1, n2, c1, c2 are single digit numbers with n1 < n2. In the examples, the ideal is symmetric to the values of n being permuted, and the values of c being be permuted.

In the first example $n_1,n_2 \in {0,1,2,3}$, while in the second example $n_1,n_2 \in {0,1,2,3,4,5}$. In both examples, $c_1,c_2 \in {0,1}$. So the first example (which is small enough to calculate a Groebner basis) has symmetry $S_4 \times S_2$, while the second example (which I have not been able to calculate a Groebner basis currently, but know many example solutions to the polynomial constraints) has symmetry $S_6 \times S_2$.

Surprising to me (maybe it should not be?), in the primary decomposition of the first example, none of the primary ideals have the full symmetry of the original ideal. I expect the same for the second example, which is why I think it would be helpful to break the symmetry somehow to remove essentially "redundant/permutated" copies of the same primary ideals in there.

I do not know a priori "how far" I need to break the symmetry. But if I knew a nice trick to break the symmetry, I could just try smaller subgroups, starting with the trivial group (i.e. fully breaking the symmetry), and see if that helps the calculations.
